# User specific commands

Tags: ubuntu

i need to try user specific commands like adding new user, changing or creating user password, user lookup information using finger command, and finally start new shell as different user. I wanna see the change that happens when these commands are used. i tried once using user add chrome ok, its like 
Permission denied

Comment: No, actually it’s not a basic question.  It’s not a question at all.  What do you want to know?  Bravo for wanting to learn by doing (experimenting), but what do you want us to tell you?

Comment: [Ubuntu User Management](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html.en)

Answer (score 2):

Start simple, there's no need to remember all the commands,
just find what you need the most.

The most common Linux commands can be [found here](http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=The-10-Most-Important-Linux-Commands)

but to answer your question here's user commands :

- Create user: `sudo adduser username`
- Delete user: `sudo deluser username`
- Add user to group: `sudo adduser username groupname`
- List user status: `sudo chage -l username`
- Change the listed details: `sudo chage username`

Notice how I used `sudo` before each command, this means the command is executed as the root user, not using `sudo` gives the access denied error.  If you still get an access denied error with sudo, talk to your SysAdmin as you're not in the `sudoers` group.

Comment: +1 for short but very relevant information.

Comment: An edit and an upvote. **:-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/494214/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**